# What are the AI levels for nights 1 to 4 in FNAF 1?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-help-wanted

What are the AI levels for each hour for nights 1 to 4 in FNAF 1? The most I can find is night 1 and I have spent the past hour or so looking. I don't care if its the actual help wanted or the original since I ***think*** they have the same type of AI code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if FNAF: Help Wanted uses different values compared to FNAF1 but [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/ujg0Y5IziiY?t=570) (link to the relevant bit) by someone who decompiled the game goes pretty in depth into the various underlying mechanics in FNAF1 including the AI levels as well as AI lvl scaling. To summarize, at the beginning of each night the various animatronics have their AI lvl set to a certain value, listed below:

| Night | Freddy | Bonnie | Chica | Foxy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 0 | 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 1-2* | 2 | 4 | 6 |
| 5 | 3 | 5 | 7 | 5 |
| 6 | 4 | 10 | 12 | 16 |

At various times throughout the night, the AI level of certain animatronics will increase for the rest of the night, outlined below:

- 2 AM: Bonnie lvl +1
- 3 AM: Bonnie, Chica, Foxy lvl +1
- 4 AM: Bonnie, Chica, Foxy lvl +1

This means that by 4AM the animatronics will now have the following AI lvls:

| Night | Freddy | Bonnie | Chica | Foxy |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 0 | 6 | 3 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 7 | 4 |
| 4 | 1-2* | 5 | 6 | 8 |
| 5 | 3 | 8 | 9 | 7 |
| 6 | 4 | 13 | 14 | 18 |

* 50/50 chance of Freddy's lvl starting at 1 or 2

Comment: I appreciate having the beginning and by 4 AM AI levels, I still have some concerns but it seems to check out, and now I need to find FNAF 2 or ask another question.

Comment: @anomanous What concerns do you have? I can't promise I can alleviate them (anything not in the linked video is probably out of my depth) but I can try

Comment: One of my concerns was that I would have thought that for 5 AM something would have gone up, plus I would have thought that Freddy would have gone to at least 5 somewhere down the line, there is a few others that I have momentarily forgotten, but like I said before for now until I remember those its good.

Comment: @anomanous I forgot to mention in the answer itself, the person who made the video claims to have decompiled the game's code, so long as that's true there's no speculation in their findings. I can't answer why nothing increases at 5AM but also note nothing happens at 1AM either. The Freddy thing is addressed in the video (https://youtu.be/ujg0Y5IziiY?t=960), the gist is Freddy is a bit special and is very tough even at AI lvl 10. I do recommend watching the video as its an interesting watch and covers a lot of topics beyond the ones mentioned so far

Answer (score 1):

Here is a list of all the A.I. levels from nights 1-5.

**Night 1:**

Foxy-0
Freddy-0
Bonnie-3
Chica-3

**Night 2:**

Foxy-5
Freddy-0
Chica-6
Bonnie-6

**Night 3:**

Foxy-10
Freddy-8
Chica-11
Bonnie-11

**Night 4:**

Foxy-15
Freddy-12
Chica-15
Bonnie-15

**Night 5:**

All 16

Comment: While I do appreciate that I have some more of the AI levels I need, the AI levels do go up from the start of the night which is demonstrated by night 1, which has all 0's at the beginning.